# Multiple nested views inside a view with ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a single web page, which is the main view instance. I then have 4 nested views inside of that, and each calls their own pages. I can get this to work with 1 nested view just fine, but if i try it with another, it fails.

The error is: Transition Rejection($id: 0 type: 6, message: The transition errored, detail: Error: Cannot transition to abstract state 'aviation_network')

The code:

```
    var app = angular.module('base_app', ['ui.router', 'controllers']);

    app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

$stateProvider

    .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: './content/start_page.html'
    })

    .state('launch_page', {
        url: '/launch_page',
        templateUrl: './content/launch_page.html'
    })

    .state('connected_aircraft', {
        url: '/connected_aircraft',
        templateUrl: './content/connected_aircraft.html'
    })

    .state('aviation_network', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/aviation_network',
        templateUrl: './content/aviation_network.html'
    })

    .state('aviation_network.home', {
            url: '',
            templateUrl: './content/what_is_sbs.html'
        })

    .state('broadband_safety', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/broadband_safety',
        templateUrl: './content/broadband_safety.html'
    })

        .state('broadband_safety.home', {
            url: '',
            templateUrl: './content/what_is_sbs.html'
        })
```

The state broadband_safety works fine, and connects up. But when I do the exact same thing with aviation_network, it fails. Why?

Comment: Why your url is empry on child?

Comment: It doesnt seem to make any difference. I added aviation_home and broadband_home to each, and I get the same error.

Comment: The error says: Cannot transition to abstract state 'aviation_network'. How do you try to change to that state? Can you show some code? And the working one with the transition to 'broadband_safety'?